# how to deploy node app to Heroku if the code is in a subfolder?

Tags: node.js, heroku

I have a nextjs and nodejs app in `client` and `server` directories respectively, and I know that heroku needs `package.json` in the root folder to deploy the node app but, it is in the `server` directory, how can I deploy this, I tried everything I found in other StackOverflow questions but they have ancient solutions, that doesn't seem to work now, is there any workaround?

```
/myProject
 -- client
 -- server
```

Answer (score 1):

It's possible to specify your start script by adding a file `Procfile` in the root directory.

You may need a `Procfile` like this:

```
web: cd client && npm start
worker: cd server && npm start
```

Next, Enable both web and worker in Heroku App > Resources Tab.

---

See the official doc also: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/deploying-nodejs#specifying-a-start-script